# linux Bluetooth programming in c

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to run a basic code of c in linux[ubuntu] to search bluetooth device, but i am facing some problem.

By using command `sudo apt-get install bluez`, to install required blueZ library it is saying that bluez is already newest version.

But error comes that not able to find `bluetooth.h` and other files in compiling C source code, with `gcc -o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth`

Is there a complete library package, or do I have to download these header files?.

I am following this [link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html)

Comment: I'am bot a C++ programmer but i think you need the sources. Bluetooth.h is a C++ header file.

Comment: Try `apt-get install libbluetooth-dev` .

Comment: apt-get is not working, can i download this package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/bluez/4.60-0ubuntu8

Comment: I am not able to use apt-get command, because i am not connected to internet, but can if i download these library from outside and use in my ubuntu PC through pendrive , is it possible 1) Glib library, 2) Dbus library,3) Bluez 4) Bluez Utilities

Comment: Here is Good Bluetooth link for future work at [DrDubbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/using-bluetooth/232500828).

Answer (score 11):

This solved my problem:

```
apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

Comment: If possible please explain what this command does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: This answer let me install PyBluez on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you didn't include the essential header.

here's an example of code to scan for bluetooth devices

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), 
            name, 0) < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s  %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free( ii );
    close( sock );
    return 0;
}
```

to compile it on linux, just do

```
gcc -o simplescan simplescan.c -lbluetooth
```

EDIT:

Original code can be found in [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html)

Comment: Did you write that code yourself or did you get it from [somewhere](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html)...?

Comment: Because you forgot to mention it in your answer.

Comment: Need to install libs :  sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev Before compile

Answer (score 3):

As for i know there no packages for these headers. You have to download the following header files from internet.

1. `bluetooth.h`
2. `hci.h`
3. `hci_lib.h`

and create a directory called "`bluetooth`" under `/usr/lib/` in your host machine and copy the above headers to `/usr/lib/bluetooth/`. Then compile your program, it should work.

Note:  while compiling link with `-lbluetooth`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the linux-headers package. On Ubuntu or Debian this is done by doing this:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers
```