# Programmatically turn on and off bluetooth visibility in FreeBSD in C

Tags: c, bluetooth, freebsd

I would like to know what is the way to turn on and off bluetooth visibility in c in a FreeBSD system (netgraph), i.e. without using 3rd party APIs and without having to run user space executables from within my program. The solution that i'm asking for, ideally, would involve only kernel system calls and (if needed) official userspace libraries from the FreeBSD project.

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408609/linux-bluetooth-programming-in-c

Comment: Perhaps in [the Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-bluetooth.html) has some info.

Comment: @Rob I should have specified that I would not ask on stackoverflow without having read the mighty Handbook and extensive research on Google.